# Start/member since dates not being set since upgrade to 5.3.2

Tags: civimember

We recently upgraded from Civi 4.6.23 to 5.3.2.  The upgrade has gone fairly smoothly, but today we discovered a problem where the Member Since and Start Dates are not being set for any new memberships started since the day we upgraded.  Though these members are being giving the status of "Current", they are not being given correct access to our site.

I've checked our error logs, and there are no errors.  I also checked the database, and the database does not have a Member Since or Start Date, and has no record of a membership in the member_log table.

In this picture, you can see that there is no date set for Member Since or Start Date:
[image]

If we got to edit the member, though, it does have a Member Since date.  But, still not Start Date.
[image]

Comment: That looks like a serious data loss. If you have logging enabled, you can update `member_since` and `start_date` columns in `civicrm_membership` table looking at the last (not empty) value in `log_civicrm_membership`.

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed which deal with dates and/or Membership?  What about custom override files?

Comment: Hi, sorry an important detail I guess I left off, this is only affecting new memberships since the upgrade.  All memberships from before are working fine.  We do not have any extensions or custom overrides that would be affecting this.

Comment: I have looked through the error logs, and there doesn't seem to be any errors causing this. There was a Geocoder error being thrown when a membership is created, but I resolved that error and it did not resolve the membership date issue.

I went back to an older version of our site, and was able to create a membership without issue.  I also updated to the latest version, and still ran into this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never found the cause to this, but ended up using a Rule in Drupal to set the member_since and join_date variables when a new membership is created.

Comment: good to know you found that as a workaround but somewhat worrying that something on your system is affecting this core feature

Comment: Make sure you check https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/39407/245 in case it is the same problem on your site @kimberlie-davis